# How to check if player is in the top 10 scores (their ranking)

Tags: php, mysql

I have players whose scores are added to the tabled and I'd like to do a check in PHP to see whether or not their score is within the top 10 or outside of the top 10.

I have the following in place and now need to add the query to sort `highscore` in `DESC` and to let me know if that `userid` is ranked in the top 10 or not.

Current:

```
    $currentuser = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }   

    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE userid=" . $currentuser);
```

Attempt:

```
    $currentuser = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }   

    $current = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE userid=" . $currentuser);
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY highscore DESC LIMIT 10");

    foreach ($res as $player) {
       if ($player = $current) {
         echo "in the top 10" }
       else {
         echo "not in the top 10"} 
    }
```

Is this correct and is it the correct logic to check if `$currentuser` is in the top 10 or can it be achieve in a cleaner way?

Comment: thats the basic idea, what you need to do is fetch the results

Comment: Thanks @Ghost but can I do it as per the above or am I going about it the wrong way, i.e.: Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying? Would fetching the results be the same as above?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to list all users, and then denote which are in the top 10, then here's one option combining the entire list into a single query using a subquery to get the top 10 players, a `case` statement and an `outer join`:

```
select p.userid, 
  case 
    when p2.userid is not null 
    then 'in the top 10'
    else 'not in the top 10'
  end intopten
from players p
  left join (select *
        from players
        order by highscore desc
        limit 10) p2 on p.userid = p2.userid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30a57/2)

---

Given your comments, this might be the easiest option:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from players
  order by highscore desc
  limit 10
) t
where userid = 1
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30a57/3)

Comment: More so just a simple PHP/MySQL query to see if the current user is in the top 10 rather than listing them all or performing any joins :)

Comment: @DT.DTDG -- ok, I understand now.  No need for any `joins` and you only need a single query.  This should be your best option.

Comment: Ok looks good - so that selects the user but how to check if it is ranked in the top 10 or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query:

```
 $query="SELECT 1 from players WHERE  $currentuser in (SELECT userid FROM players ORDER BY highscore DESC LIMIT 10) LIMIT 1"
if($result=$mysqli->query($query))
{
if($result->num_rows >0 )echo 'in top 10';
else echo 'not in top 10';
}
else echo 'error';
```

Comment: Thanks @Ormoz, is that the cleanest way of doing it - using `$result`?

Comment: If I were you, I'd write this way

Comment: Thank you, will test it shortly :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WHERE " . $currentuser . " in` and even then still echo'ing "error"

Comment: I modified it, to be quicker, and checked it myself. it works for me. (an `else` was missing, sorry)

Comment: Ok still can't get it working. If I do it your way and `echo $query` it looks fine, but the check doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you get exactly?

Comment: you probably have a syntax error in the $query, check to see if field names are correctly spelled. they are case sensitive also. you may replace `echo 'error';` with `echo $mysqli->error;` to see the exact error

Comment: is `$currentuser` an `int`? put `echo $query` at the end and run the result query in `phpMyAdmin` to find the error source